# How to obtain the same result as numpy.where over a 2D array without getting 2 indices from the same row

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array with booleans:

```
bool_array.shape
Out[84]: (78, 8)

bool_array.dtype
Out[85]: dtype('bool')
```

And I would like to find the indices where the second dimension is True:

```
bool_array[30:35]
Out[87]: 
array([[False, False, False, False,  True, False, False, False],
       [ True, False, False, False,  True, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False,  True, False, False],
       [ True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [ True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]], dtype=bool)
```

I have been using [numpy.where](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to do this, but sometimes there are more than 1 indices along the second dimension with the True value.

I would like to find a way to obtain the same result as numpy.where but avoiding to have 2 indices from the same row:

```
np.where(bool_array)[0][30:35]
Out[88]: array([30, 31, 31, 32, 33])
```

I currently solve this by looping over the results of numpy.where, finding which n indices are equal to n-1, and using [numpy.delete](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html) to remove the unwanted indices.

I would like to know if there is a more directly way to obtain the kind of results that I want.

Notes:

- The rows of the boolean arrays that I use **always** have at least 1
  True value.
- I don't care which one of the multiples True values remains, i only
  care to have just 1.

Comment: Aren't you looking for the column indices instead? IIUC, shouldn't we be picking anyone from `np.where(bool_array)[1]` corresponding to the duplicates in np.where(bool_array)[0]?

Comment: Yes. The results I'm using are the ones from np.where(bool_array)[1], but looking at that results there is no way to find out in which row I get the "duplicate" True. I'm interested in using the results from the columns but whith the condition that there is any indices repeating themselves in np.where(bool_array)[0]. To clarify: I want a np.where(bool_array)[1] with the same lenght as bool_array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC and given the fact that there is at least one `TRUE` element per row, you can simply use [`np.argmax`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) along the second axis to select the first `TRUE` element along each row, like so -

```
col_idx = bool_array.argmax(1)
```

Sample run -

```
In [246]: bool_array
Out[246]: 
array([[ True,  True,  True,  True, False],
       [False, False,  True,  True, False],
       [ True,  True, False, False,  True],
       [ True,  True, False, False,  True]], dtype=bool)

In [247]: np.where(bool_array)[0]
Out[247]: array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3])

In [248]: np.where(bool_array)[1]
Out[248]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 0, 1, 4, 0, 1, 4])

In [249]: bool_array.argmax(1)
Out[249]: array([0, 2, 0, 0])
```

Explanation -

Corresponding to the duplicates from the output of `np.where(bool_array)[0]`, i.e. :

```
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3])
```

, we need to select anyone from the output of `np.where(bool_array)[1]`, i.e. :

```
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 0, 1, 4, 0, 1, 4])
       ^           ^     ^        ^
```

Thus, selecting the first `True` from each row with `bool_array.argmax(1)` gives us :

```
array([0, 2, 0, 0])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could call [`np.unique`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) on the resultant array like so:

```
>>> np.where(bool_array)[0][30:35]
Out[4]: array([0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> np.unique(np.where(bool_array)[0][30:35])
Out[5]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
```